# Input (Auto)Correlation Matrix for LMS Adaptive Algorithm

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, autocorrelation, lms

I read quite a few posts regarding the autocorrelation matrix and although some of them were of the LMS adaptive algorithm application, I didn't find an answer to my question.
[image]

How do I calculate R; that is, the expected value of the matrix ( x' * x ) shown above, with x being a column vector.  If x(t) is a sine wave, the following is the solution, which can be extended beyond the dimension of 2x2

[image]

My issue is that I have multiple sine waves (and I don't know how many there will be at a given period of time).  For example, with t=0:0.001:1, x=2*sin(2*pi*10*t) + 4*sin(2*pi*20*t) + 3*sin(2*pi*30*t).  What is the input correlation matrix for this signal?  What is the general formula/algorithm/Matlab-function(s) to calculate them?

Apology for my inability to use LaTeX to formulate this my question as I noted in other posts and some bizarre spacing in the images as I deleted irrelevant texts.